# Code syntaxhighlighting does not work in "About Me"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, syntax-highlighting, markdown-preview

I placed some source-code in the *"About Me"* section and it does not seem to work properly.

During the formatting `<!-- language: java -->` results syntax-highlighted code in the preview box but after saving, on the profile page the code which should be formatted is just a simple text with grey background and consolase fonttype.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We don't support syntax highlighting in the profile. If you want to make a case for why we should, a feature request would be fine.

I'll see about turning the preview off (thanks for pointing that out, Patrick!) to match the server-side behaviour.

Comment: Agreed. Doesn't seem useful, but can the editor be fixed then? It is confusing now.

Comment: @PatrickHofman What do you mean? Fixed how?

Comment: According to OP the highlighting seems to work in the preview box, but not in the end result. That seems a bug to me.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Ahh, I missed that part. Sorry about that. I'll see about turning that off.

Comment: Retagged better now.

Comment: @AdamLear is there a regression wrt the preview? I just saw a fresh post on MSO about it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388031/578411.  Maybe the code fences are to blame?

Comment: A recent request to this effect: [Please support syntax highlighting in user profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394849/335251)