# Could we possibly get a "featured program" section for profiles on Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, profile-page

I would love to see a section on profiles where users could post small code snippets (<75ish lines) that they are particularly proud of. This could be a form of self recognition for advancing in a language, "first program written without help", or "A strange programming quirk I found". This could give users a self-goal to work towards, rather than just badges, this may also increase the chance of people staying on the site to learn whatever language they want. Therefore, leading to an increase of more experienced programmers who can then further help the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can already do this. I see a lot of whitespace on your profile page:

[image: profile page of question author]

and you can [edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) it to include code; it supports most post formatting, including (non-runnable) code snippets. (The preview suggests syntax highlighting works, if it's enabled on the site; unfortunately, it doesn't, which you'll notice when you save and go back to the Profile tab.)

In fact, many users already do this, though they usually post code which does something funny. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8178633/peter-bowman) is an example.

Comment: *Even syntax highlighting works* does it? Only in the preview IIRC.

Comment: [Heh, you're right of course.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252222/code-syntaxhighlighting-does-not-work-in-about-me#comment1082023_252253)

Comment: Oh, I entirely spaced about that, thanks