# Please support syntax highlighting in user profiles

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, code-formatting

I found a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) report about this: [Code syntaxhighlighting does not work in "About Me"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252222/1377755)

The answer by a staff member says:

> If you want to make a case for why we should, a feature request would be fine.

I have searched for such a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), but I did not find any, so I am creating one myself.

---

Currently, if we put this in our profile and click save:

````
```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    return puts("Hello, World!") < 0;
}
```
````

We will see this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    return puts("Hello, World!") < 0;
}
```

Instead of this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    return puts("Hello, World!") < 0;
}
```

Profiles should support syntax highlighting for the same reasons posts should. They improve readability. Especially for code snippets, people want to show off by putting them in their profile. We should be able to effectively show readable code snippets in our profile and syntax highlighting would improve that. I thought our profile was our own, to put whatever we want in there (within reason), but we cannot even have syntax-highlighted code there.

Please support colorful code in profiles, unless there is some pressing reason not to, in which case I would like to know what that reason is.

Comment: Why not? Because currently [only few sites support code highlight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313385/what-sites-have-the-code-formatting-filter-enabled), and to make this work it should be supported on all sites. Why not? Because it means loading lots of unneeded resources for no good reason. Waste of bandwidth, waste of loading time. If one wants pretty code snippet in the profile, image would be just fine.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry Then maybe they should be shown as highlighted but only when viewed from the sites that support it. I see no reason to make sites that *could* easily support it because they already support it for posts, not support it for users.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry It seems the question you linked is not at all related to the issue here. That one seems to be about the 'your post contains text that is not properly formatted as code' message. Are you sure you did not mean to link [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314553/1377755) instead? In which case that is a bit more than 'a few' sites.